# problem while installing

Tags: boot

I am facing the issue while installing ubuntu

The boot starts I get the purple screen, 
Then after that I get the black screen
And nothing after that.

Can anyone guide me how to undercome this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Specify your hardware. What CPU? What GPU? etc.
2. Do you already have some OS (Windoze) running on your system? If yes, why don't you try installing Ubuntu in a VirtualBox VM, play with it, get comfortable and then move onto installing it on real hardware. NOTE: this is not meant to imply that installing Ubuntu directly onto some hardware is tough.

HTH!

Comment: I have intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2200 @2.20  GHz ,2 GB RAM ..I have windows xp intalled on my computer.

Comment: Can someone help me in getting out from this error.